# Generar una tabla en jquery e insertar datos

Tags: jquery

Buenas, genero un formulario en una ventana modal y ahora quiero que se plasme su contenido.

Había pensado mostrarlo en una tabla, pero la verdad no se como generarla y decir como y donde insertar cada valor del formulario anterior.

Pero no se como se podría hacer. De entrada he creado la variable tabla, pero una vez aquí ya no se como decirle cuantas filas y columnnas ha de hacer y luego como insertar en ellas su respectivo contenido.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Salud.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var contadorObjetivo = 0; //Contador para añadir objetivo con sus respectivos ejercicios.
  var contadorEjercicio = 0; //Contador para añadir ejercicios.

  // JS para crear rutinas estilo POWER

  $('#Anyadir-Rutina-btn').click(function() {

    // Hacemos aparecer la ventana modal donde rellenamos formulario.
    $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').css({
      'display': 'flex',
      'height': 'auto',
      'width': '80%'
    });

    // Creamos las variables donde se describen todos los elementos del formulario
    var titulo1 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Introduce un título general" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo1" />';
    var titulo2 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Objetivo" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo2" />';
    var titulo3 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Ejercicio" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo3" />';
    var titulo4 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Herramienta" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo4" />';
    var titulo5 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Rondas" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo5" />';
    var titulo6 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Repeticiones" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo6" />';
    var titulo7 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Propuesta de peso" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo7" />';
    var titulo8 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Peso usado" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo8" />';

    var cerrarModalBtn = '<input type="button" value="Cancelar" class="Inputs-Modal BtnFormulario" id="cerrar-modal-btn" />';
    var mostrarModalBtn = '<input type="button" value="Mostrar" class="Inputs-Modal BtnFormulario" id="Mostrar-modal-btn" />';


    // Insertamos los elementos para que el usuario rellene el formulario
    $('#ModalFila1').append(titulo1);
    $('#ModalFila2').append(titulo2);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo3);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo4);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo5);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo6);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo7);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo8);

    $('#ModalFila1').append(cerrarModalBtn);
    $('#ModalFila1').append(mostrarModalBtn);

    // Botón mostrar. Guarda y muestra los datos escritos en el formulario. ¡¡NO VA!!
    $('#Mostrar-modal-btn').click(function() {

      var Resultado1 = $("#Titulo1").val();
      var Resultado2 = $("#Titulo2").val();
      var Resultado3 = $("#Titulo3").val();
      var Resultado4 = $("#Titulo4").val();
      var Resultado5 = $("#Titulo5").val();
      var Resultado6 = $("#Titulo6").val();
      var Resultado7 = $("#Titulo7").val();
      var Resultado8 = $("#Titulo8").val();

      var tabla = '<table></table>';
    });
  });

});
```

```css
#Power-Contenedor h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#Anyadir-Rutina-btn {
  background-color: #21211d;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#Modal-Escribir-Rutina {
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  background-color: #21211d;
  margin: auto;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.ModalFila {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.Inputs-Modal {
  padding: 3px;
}

.TextoFormulario {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.BtnFormulario {
  background-color: #fdd063;
  border-color: transparent;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  float: right;
}

#Titulo1 {
  width: 80%;
}

#Titulo2 {
  width: 80%;
}

#Titulo3 {
  width: 40%;
}

#Mostrar-modal-btn {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Power-Contenedor">

  <h1> Apartado Formulario </h1>

  <a href="#" id="Anyadir-Rutina-btn"> Añadir entreno </a>

  <div id="Modal-Escribir-Rutina">
    <div class="ModalFila" id="ModalFila1"></div>
    <div class="ModalFila" id="ModalFila2"></div>
    <div class="ModalFila" id="ModalFila3"></div>
    <div class="ModalFila" id="ModalFila"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="Final-Escribir-Rutina">
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero que te puedo recomendar es que no debes generar una estructura **HTML** tan grande desde tu JS, **esto es considerado una mala práctica**, lo mejor es crear la estructura principal en el **DOM** y luego por medio del atributo `display` de **CSS** mostrar u ocultar las secciones cuando sea necesario, al hacer esto tu código se entenderá mucho más fácil lo que será un punto a favor a la hora de hacer soporte en un futuro.

Te dejo un ejemplo funcional de la funcionalidad que solicitabas, si tienes dudas con gusto las respondo.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var contadorObjetivo = 0; //Contador para añadir objetivo con sus respectivos ejercicios.
    var contadorEjercicio = 0; //Contador para añadir ejercicios.
    
    // JS para crear rutinas estilo POWER
    $('#Anyadir-Rutina-btn').click(function() {
    
        // Hacemos aparecer la ventana modal donde rellenamos formulario.
        $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').css({
            'display': 'flex',
            'height': 'auto',
            'width': '80%'
        });
    
        // Botón mostrar. Guarda y muestra los datos escritos en el formulario. ¡¡NO VA!!
        $('#Mostrar-modal-btn').click(function() {
            var Resultado1 = $("#Titulo1").val();
            var Resultado2 = $("#Titulo2").val();
            var Resultado3 = $("#Titulo3").val();
            var Resultado4 = $("#Titulo4").val();
            var Resultado5 = $("#Titulo5").val();
            var Resultado6 = $("#Titulo6").val();
            var Resultado7 = $("#Titulo7").val();
            var Resultado8 = $("#Titulo8").val();
        
            $("#Final-Escribir-Rutina table tbody").append('<tr><td>'+ Resultado1 +'</td><td>'+ Resultado2 +'</td><td>'+ Resultado3 +'</td><td>'+ Resultado4 +'</td><td>'+ Resultado5 +'</td><td>'+ Resultado6 +'</td><td>'+ Resultado7 +'</td><td>'+ Resultado8 +'</td></tr>');

            $("#Final-Escribir-Rutina").css('display', 'block');

            $("#Titulo1").val('');
            $("#Titulo2").val('');
            $("#Titulo3").val('');
            $("#Titulo4").val('');
            $("#Titulo5").val('');
            $("#Titulo6").val('');
            $("#Titulo7").val('');
            $("#Titulo8").val('');
        });
    });
});
```

```css
#Power-Contenedor h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#Anyadir-Rutina-btn {
    background-color: #21211d;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#Modal-Escribir-Rutina {
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    background-color: #21211d;
    margin: auto;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.ModalFila {
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.Inputs-Modal {
    padding: 3px;
}

.TextoFormulario {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.BtnFormulario {
    background-color: #fdd063;
    border-color: transparent;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    float: right;
}

#Titulo1 {
    width: 80%;
}

#Titulo2 {
    width: 80%;
}

#Titulo3 {
    width: 40%;
}

#Mostrar-modal-btn {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#Final-Escribir-Rutina{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="Power-Contenedor">

    <h1> Apartado Formulario </h1>

    <a href="#" id="Anyadir-Rutina-btn"> Añadir entreno </a>

    <div id="Modal-Escribir-Rutina">
        <div class="ModalFila" id="ModalFila1">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Introduce un título general" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo1" />
        </div>
        <div class="ModalFila" id="ModalFila2">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Objetivo" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo2" />
        </div>
        <div class="ModalFila" id="ModalFila3">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Ejercicio" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo3" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Herramienta" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo4" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Rondas" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo5" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Repeticiones" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo6" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Propuesta de peso" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo7" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Peso usado" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" id="Titulo8" />
        </div>
        <div class="ModalFila" id="ModalFila">
            <input type="button" value="Cancelar" class="Inputs-Modal BtnFormulario" id="cerrar-modal-btn" />
            <input type="button" value="Mostrar" class="Inputs-Modal BtnFormulario" id="Mostrar-modal-btn" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <br><br>

    <div id="Final-Escribir-Rutina">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Título general</th>
                    <th>Objetivo</th>
                    <th>Ejercicio</th>
                    <th>Herramienta</th>
                    <th>Rondas</th>
                    <th>Repeticiones</th>
                    <th>Propuesta de peso</th>
                    <th>Peso Usado</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**NOTA:** he incluido **Bootstrap** únicamente para los estilos de la tabla, tu puedes omitirlo y simplemente aplicar tus propios estilos.